# What is the bandwidth limit for Google Drive file uploads?

Tags: google-drive, upload

The [Google Drive help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2424368) states that one's storage quota "includes plenty of bandwidth for ordinary use". In practice, about how much does this amount to?

Is Google Drive suitable for hosting for public downloads, or is the bandwidth limit likely to kick in fairly quickly?

Answer (score 5):

Google says not to worry unless "there is an egregious amount of bandwidth use."

[Google Docs Help Forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Docs/thread?tid=4abf7b6e6994865c&hl=en)
.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't really help me know what they define "egregious" to be... I was hoping someone would have had some specific experience with what they'll allow or not allow

Comment: I've noticed that the guys at http://www.informationisbeautiful.net/ often host the sources behind their visualisation in public google spreadsheets (this one for instance: http://www.informationisbeautiful.net/visualizations/snake-oil-supplements/). I'm not sure what their bandwidth usage is like but they don't seem to have experienced any problems.